# My muslim neighbour (F) takes sunbaths in the back garden without covering, is there a problem me seen her?

Tags: non-muslim, hijab, men-women

I am not a muslim and I live in a detached house but I can see my neighbours' backgarden, who are muslim, from my home office. I work from home most of the time, so, I spend a lot of time at my desk, which is near the window.

One of my neighbours always wears a hijab on the street, but she often takes sunbaths without the hijab and wearing shorts. I was wondering if me seen her like this could be problematic (due to the contrast of clothes on the street vs. backgarden). I am not saying I am snooping, it is just that I am at the window working while she is at the backgarden enjoying the sun. Also, I am not the only neighbour in this situation as there are at least 8 neighbours who can see each other's backgardens, and many of us also use the backgarden to take sunbaths (but other neighbours are not muslim too).

Comment: From an Islamic point of view it is not permissible to look at a non-mahram female's body. Nor is it permissible to look into your neighbor's house. You can tell her what you have told us, as it is possible that she does not realize that she is visible and it might be that she would want to change her location or use some sort of curtain or fence to ensure her privacy.

Comment: @UmH That is a good point. However, I feel me knocking on their door to break this news may also be unwelcome. Just trying to think how I would feel if I was in that situation. It is an open back garden with low fences. It is not too difficult to guess that other neighbours can see you, as you can actually see them too. But I think your comment gives me a good hint about how problematic this situation can be.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good chance she would appreciate knowing that she is visible to others around her. The Islamic requirement of hijab is not based on whether you are at home or outside; it is about whether you are in view of non-relatives or not, so being visible like this would potentially be problematic.

If you can find a way to inform her that she is in the open view in a subtle and non-confrontational way, try to do so. For example, leave a note at her door or in her mailbox. You don't need to tell her what she should or should not do; simply inform her that she is visible to you and to others, in case she was not aware, and that you thought she might want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to not look at her and tell her that she is visible to her neighbours, so that she will maintain hijab.

You can also try to politely tell her she should maintain her hijab.

Thanks for your question.